# <FallbackStorage: request=<WSGIRequest: GET ''>>

Tags: django

Hi I have following setup:
Views.py

```
def employerSignupView(request):
if request.method =="POST":
    form = EmployerSignupForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        messages.success(request,'Hooray !! you have account with us now!!')
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        messages.success(request, 'There has been problem registering new account with us. Please try again')
        form=EmployerSignupForm()
form=EmployerSignupForm()
return render(request, 'employerSignup.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('signup/employer/', views.employerSignupView, name='employerSignup'),
path('signup/jobSeeker/', views.jobSeekerSignupView, name='jobSeekerSignup'),
path('login/', views.user_login, name ='login'),
path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
path('myaccount/',views.myaccount, name='myaccount'),
```

]
forms.py

```
class EmployerSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
username= forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": "Username", "class": "form-control", "type": "text"}))
email= forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": "Your email", "class": "form-control", "type": "email"}))
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": "Buisness Name", "class": "form-control", "type": "text"}))
last_name =forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": "Type", "class": "form-control", "type": "text"}))
password1 =forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": "Password", "class": "form-control", "type": "password"}))
password2 =forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": "Re-type Password", "class": "form-control", "type": "password"}))
streetAddress = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": "Street Address", "class": "form-control", "type": "text"}))
suburb = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": "Suburb", "class": "form-control", "type": "text"}))
postcode = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": "Postcode", "class": "form-control", "type": "text"}))
phoneNumber = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": "Phone Number", "class": "form-control", "type": "tel"}))
website = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": "Website", "class": "form-control", "type": "url"}))
class Meta:
    model= Employer
    fields= ('first_name', 'last_name','username' ,'email', 'streetAddress', 'suburb', 'postcode', 'phoneNumber', 'password1', 'password2' )
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
class Role(models.TextChoices):
    ADMIN = 'ADMIN', 'Admin'
    EMPLOYER = 'EMPLOYER', 'Employer'
    JOBSEEKER = 'JOBSEEKER', 'Job Seeker'
base_role = Role.ADMIN 
role= models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=Role.choices, null=False)
streetAddress = models.CharField(max_length=100)
suburb = models.CharField(max_length=50)
postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=15)


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk :
        self.role=self.base_role
        return super().save(self, *args, **kwargs)

class Employer(User):
    last_name = None
    role= User.Role.EMPLOYER
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)



class JobSeeker(User):
    role= User.Role.JOBSEEKER
    birthDate = models.DateField()
    resume = models.FileField(upload_to='static/resume')
```

I am unable to create an account. and there is a weird thing whenever I hit submit button on  the page it pops <FallbackStorage: request=<WSGIRequest: GET ''>> instead of the message that I had setup when error occurs.
[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOOry.png)
jobSeekerSignup.html

```
        {%extends 'navbar.html'%}
    
    {%block content%}
    
    {%if messages%}
    {% for message in messages%}
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
         {{messages}}
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    
    {%endfor%}
    {%endif%}
    
    <div class="container login-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3>Create an account with us!! </h3>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    {%csrf_token%}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                            {{form.first_name}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                            {{form.last_name}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{form.username}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{form.email}}
                    </div>                
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{form.streetAddress}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                            {{form.suburb}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                            {{form.postcode}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{form.phoneNumber}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{form.resume}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{form.password1}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{form.password2}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btnSubmit btn-primary" value="Sign up" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>Already user?  <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="ForgetPwd">Log in</a></p>
    
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{%endblock content%}
```

Could you help with this??

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

```
{%if messages%}
{% for message in messages%}
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
     **{{messages}}**
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>

{%endfor%}
{%endif%}
```

Here in the code, you are using {{messages}} instead of {{message}}, so that was it you will see your code working.